# How can I use map with a string got from getLine?[Haskell]

Tags: haskell, dictionary, getline

I want to read a String and toUpper all the characters.

```
import Data.Char

main = do 
    a <- getLine
    b <- getLine
    map toUpper a
    if (a == b) 
        then print 0
        else if (a < b) 
            then print (-1)
            else print 1
```

---

Then I got this

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO a0' with actual type `[b0]'
    In the return type of a call of `map'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: map toUpper a
    In the expression:
      do { a <- getLine;
           b <- getLine;
           map toUpper a;
           if (a == b) then
               print 0
           else
               if (a < b) then print (- 1) else print 1 }
```

---

Hou can I use map with a String got from getLine?
Or there is another way to read a String and toUpper all the characters ?

Comment: let lift f x = return (f x) in getLine >>= lift (map toUpper)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not assigning the "result" of your `map` call to anything at all.  This is causing the type error you are getting, which is telling you that you are trying to return a string (the result of the `map` call), when it really needs to be some `IO` type.

A direct fix would look something like this:

```
import Data.Char

main = do 
    a <- getLine
    b <- getLine
    let c = map toUpper a
    if (c == b) 
        then print 0
        else if (c < b) 
            then print (-1)
            else print 1
```

If you use `fmap` you can `toUpper` all the chars and get the line of input at the same time (preventing the need for a `c`).

```
import Data.Char

main = do
    a <- fmap (map toUpper) getLine
    b <- getLine
    if a == b
        then print 0
        else if a < b
            then print (-1)
            else print 1
```

Answer (score 7):

Others have corrected your program in the minimal way, but I want to point out a C-ism that Haskell has improved:

```
if (a == b)
    then print 0
    else if (a < b)
        then print (-1)
        else print 1
```

Has it ever bothered you that *numbers* were appropriated for recording how a thing compared? It's certainly bothered me. Fortunately, defining new data types in Haskell is so cheap that we do it all the time. In the standard library, there's a type defined as follows:

```
data Ordering = LT | EQ | GT
```

And there's a standard function

```
compare :: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering
```

So why not use this beautiful Haskell artifact?

```
main = do
    a <- getLine
    b <- getLine
    print (compare (map toUpper a) b)
```

Comment: I was going to mention this, but I wasn't sure if the OP required the values of 0, 1, and -1.  Aside from that, your version is much better.

Comment: @nponeccop, ah thanks... I though something like that probably existed, I just couldn't find it.  (I guess I should've used hoogle :), a quick search returned `fromEnum`)

Answer (score 4):

in Haskell it's a good practice to separate non-monadic code from monadic one.

A very minimal improvement is to move `print` outwards:

```
print $ if (a == c) 
    then 0
    else if (a < b) 
        then (-1)
        else 1
```

As for an idiomatic solution, think of separating all non-monadic code in a separate function (both comparison and uppercasing).

Also, if you see `elsif` in your code, think about guards:

```
c_compare a c
    | a == c = 0
    | a < c = -1
    | otherwise = 1
```

A case implementation is also possible:

```
c_compare a c = case (compare a c) of
    LT -> -1
    EQ -> 0
    GT -> 1
```

Comment: Or (rather horrible) `c_compare a c = fromEnum (compare a c) - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, everything in Haskell is immutable, so calling `map toUpper a` doesn't actually modify `a`. If you'd like to save that result, you'll have to bind it to a variable in a `let` clause. So you might want to change your code to something like this:

```
import Data.Char

main = do 
    a <- getLine
    b <- getLine
    let c = map toUpper a
    if (a == c) 
        then print 0
        else if (a < b) 
            then print (-1)
            else print 1
```